# Run-time error in c# - An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I am new for c# and here I've got this error when I run my C# code. please any one give me a efficient way to solve this..

[Run-time error - An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj5bG.png)

```
private void textBox13_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand comm1 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT `l_points` FROM `customer` WHERE `ph_no` ='" + Convert.ToInt32(textBox13.Text) + "'", conn);
            //MySqlDataReader mdr = comm1.ExecuteReader();
            //MessageBox.Show(comm1.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            //textBox12.Text = comm1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            MySqlDataReader red = comm1.ExecuteReader();

        if(red.Read())
        {
            textBox12.Text = red.GetString("l_points");
            conn.Close();
            conn.Open();
            //int x = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox12.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)) +Convert.ToInt32 (textBox10.Text);
            //string qry = "Update customer SET l-points = x where ph_no= '"+Convert.ToInt32(textBox13.Text)+"'";



            //////
           MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("Update customer SET l_points = '"+((Convert.ToInt32(textBox12.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)) 
                                                        +Convert.ToInt32 (textBox10.Text))+"' where ph_no= '" + Convert.ToInt32(textBox13.Text) + "'", conn);
           da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("update sucess!!!!!!");
        }
        conn.Close();

        //double bal = Convert.ToDouble(textBox7.Text) * 0.01;
        ////double bal = 1000;
        ////MessageBox.Show(textBox7.Text);
        //textBox10.Text = bal.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: paste the code here on which you get this error .

Comment: Be also careful about SQL injection, use parameters whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use int.TryParse to try parsing the text to integer first before the parsing happens. With Convert.ToInt32, if there is an error in the string, it will load an exception.

```
int number10 = 0, number12 = 0, number2 = 0;
int.TryParse(textBox10.Text, out number10);
int.TryParse(textBox12.Text, out number12);
int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out number2);

int l_points = number12 - number2 + number10;
```

Also you can debug each row to know what and where the issue is

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you trying to equal a datetime value with a string value you can try DateTime.Parse in case you want to convert it

Answer (score 0):

Value in one of your text boxes is not convertible to number or integer. It is plain text, and you are using Convert.ToInt32 to convert it to integer. That is why, you are getting the error. Also, calculate your number before this statement.

```
int l_points = ((Convert.ToInt32(textBox12.Text) -
 Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)) +Convert.ToInt32 (textBox10.Text)); 

int phone = Convert.ToInt32(textBox13.Text); 

MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("Update customer SET l_points = "+l_points +" where ph_no= " + phone, conn);
```

> Moreso, you should not be creating SQL statements like this to avoid SQL injection. Use it as input parameters and if possible, stored procedures.

Comment: Sorry.. Still getting the same error on  this. << int l_points = ((Convert.ToInt32(textBox12.Text) -
 Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)) +Convert.ToInt32 (textBox10.Text)); >>

Comment: Check your values. Is any textbox value text or blank. Convert blank value to 0.